# i need help to resolve jquery conflict between video player and fancy box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, conflict

i need help to resolve jquery conflict problem between video player jquery and fancy box jquery ?

**Video Player Scripts**

```
<script src="videoplayer/videos/video.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="videoplayer/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Fancy Box Scripts**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
```

**Problem**

```
jquery.easing.1.3.js script conflict with fancybox lightbox jquery? 

when i used this method then video player not working properly  

<script src="videoplayer/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a conflict between two libs, try

```
$.noConflict();
```

or

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

More information on noConflict : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: already used this method but video player is not working properly
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>`

Comment: And why you include two times jquery? One time with http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js and one time with jquery-1.10.1.min.js. It can add conflict.

Comment: both jquery are in different pages

Comment: If you create a jsFiddle to simulate the problem, I could resolve it